# TSVN DNS error: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Tags: svn, dns, tortoisesvn

I've updated my TortoiseSVN client and now I'm getting the error when trying to update or commit to different repositories:

> The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was
>   found

Any ideas on how I can solve this? Internet Explorer shows up appropriate URL just fine.

*TortoiseSVN 1.5.3, Build 13783.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys, thanks for your answers. Everything was fixed by yet another reboot (2 reboots after TSVN update).

Still I can't explain what happened. :)

Comment: Well, thanks for reporting. At least we know that updating and rebooting solves a problem.

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling to resolve this problom..atlast i found a solution...

in the URL provided, give IP Address instead of ServerName

eg:  'http://xxx.xxx.x.x:8080/svn/RepositoryName'

i got the problom fixed by doing this...

hope this piece of information will help

Answer (score 4):

This error being reported is a winsock one, rather than being particular to TSVN. From [Windows Sockets Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668(VS.85).aspx):

> The requested name is valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the correct associated data being resolved for, e.g. an MX record is returned but no A record - indicating the host itself exists, but is not directly reachable.

It is strange that you can access the host via IE however. Is it possible that in TSVN you've specified a port number that isn't available on the remote host, and IE is accessing the host on port 80?

Comment: just to add ... running Visual SVN Server on Windows Server 2008 uses the computer name as part of the repository url (e.g. https :// somecomputername:8443/svn/repo1). If IIS is installed on the same server, your computer name may already be assigned to the default website (that's what i experienced on my VPS). To get around this, just use the IP address instead of the computer name for the url (e.g. https :// 123.123.123.123:8443/svn/repo1).

Answer (score 3):

Did you change the connection protocol (eg. from svn to http or from http to https)? Or did any firewall configuration between your PC and the SVN server change? SVN over HTTP uses DAV verbs to perform actions, so it might be that these are blocked in a firewall.

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is an old thread but I've just experienced the same problem and found a solution so no harm in sharing.

The solution for me involved setting the appropriate proxy settings within **TortoiseSVN | Settings | Network** (which were already setup in my browser, hence being able to view the repository fine there). So if you are behind a proxy server, make sure you setup TortoiseSVN appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to run both TeamCity and Visual SVN Server on the same virtual pc. Turning of the TeamCity services solved the problem for me. It is possible that the two web servers was having a little struggle with each other.

Comment: Maybe the TeamCity and VisualSVN servers were trying to use the same port. You might want to check that.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all solutions, but the mixture of them worked.

1. Erase all valid lines under C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Subversion\servers
2. Erase all valid lines under C:\ProgramData\Subversion\servers
3. Open TortoiseSvn -> network then uncheck "enable proxy server"

worked for me. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a static IP resulting in no DNS server. Set your IP to DHCP and it will help.