# Unable to checkout project using svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I try to checkout this project :

https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-ajax/trunk/

I receive the error :

[image]

'src.springframework.org' is a valid hostname so what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at the suggestions in those answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171805/tsvn-dns-error-the-requested-name-is-valid-but-no-data-of-the-requested-type-w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tortoise is misconfigured.

I tried the command : svn checkout https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-ajax/trunk/ , and it works perfectly well.

How did you configured tortoise?

Yuo can try my command with putty, for example.

edit : Your hostname is not root or something else ?